# get to server's variables when run php in console

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I have in my crontab something like this:

> wget http://myurl.com/myscript.php

This work , but must now replace wget by php.

The problem is that I have access to $_SERVER [ ' DOCUMENT_ROOT '] and fail my includes

How I can do it without changing my php ? .

Thank you.

PS: sorry for my English .

Comment: "replace wget by php" - what exactly are you trying to do? Download remote file or to just output its contents ?

Comment: He requested by the Server Manager as a matter of performance

Comment: maybe I'm not being clear ... I have an instruction set in the crontab using wget and need to replace the instruction by php, but I can not access configuration variables like $ _SERVER is there any way ?

Comment: specify project 'root' path directly like `var/www/project/public/index.php`

Comment: apparently that might work . I test on Monday and tell you. thanks

Comment: no works...ive change my php if(isset($argv[0]) )$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 'var/www/html' is a very bad solution, but.... thanks Roman.